# How to retrieve covariance matrices in OpenCV's EM-algorithm?

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to implement a GMM using OpenCV's EM algorithm. Everything works just fine, except I cannot access the covariance matrices after the model is trained. Trying to access them always results in an access violation. I use the C++ API, since the C API is marked as deprecated in the documentation.

First I used OpenCV Version 2.4.9. Implementing a GMM model is super easy in OpenCV:

```
EM model (3);
Mat probs;
bool b = model.train (samples, noArray(), noArray(), probs);
Mat means = model.get<Mat>("means");                  // --> correct values.
vector<Mat> sigmas = model.get<vector<Mat>>("covs");  // --> access violation.
```

Since I experienced similar version problems with other OpenCV packages in the past, I upgraded to OpenCV 3.0 Beta and tried again (interface is slightly different in 3.0):

```
ml::EM::Params emps = ml::EM::Params::Params (3);
Mat probs;
Ptr<ml::EM> model = ml::EM::train (samples, noArray(), noArray(), probs, emps);
Mat means = model->getMeans();                      // same mean values, all correct
std::vector<Mat> sigmas;                            
model->getCovs (sigmas);                            // --> access violation
```

Now I am confused. Am I doing some stupid mistake or is there a continuous bug in OpenCV? In both cases I convinced myself that the model is well trained, and that the probability-values and the means are correct. So I expect the covariance matrices are correct too, but I cannot manage to access them. Before I switch back to an older version and the C API, which appearently worked at some time

What mistake did I make?

Comment: I've just tried to execute some code similar to yours and it works just fine (in 2.4.9). If you compare to some examples you may find anything suspicious: http://subokita.com/2014/03/24/image-segmentation-using-opencvs-expectation-maximization/ . Anyway, my guess is that the error has something to do with the nature and format of the input data. Good luck, and let us know if you fix it! ;)

Comment: @KeillRandor: My input data is of the format Mat(500,2,CV_32FC1) and resembles a fairly trivial distribution. I could not find an example where someone tries to access the covariance matrices, so I expect, that this is a bug in the OpenCV versions I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this
gmm.getMatVector("covs")[i], where i is the cluster.